Reference book needed
Any suggestions for a reference book that is a "Who's Who" of persons named in the Tanach?  Persons do appear in multiple places (such as in Shmuel and Divrei Hayamim, or in the lives of David and later Shlomo)), and are often children/grandchildren of others but their relationship is not stated. A reference work to keep near a tanach, and simpler than a concordance, would be useful when a quick answer is needed.
Hebrew and English language texts both would work.
Thank you.

https://www.nli.org.il/en/books/NNL_ALEPH990043653230205171/NLI

English version: https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899060255.html

אישי התנ"ך
Ishei Hatanach - Encyclopedia Of Biblical Personalities
by Yishai Chasida

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

B"H
An online resources is the Hebrew Wikisource page on "people in Tanach".
They have a list of every person listed in Tanach, with a brief description of who they are, and often times links to other website(s) for more elaboration.
As an example, under "converts", it lists Ovadia, with references to the Midrash and Rashi about him.
